# mysql rollback after reboot

Tags: mysql, centos6, parallels

I did a server reboot yesterday, after the restart my Mysql database did a 20 days (2014/06/06) rollback. I have not any clues about what happened.
I do backup everyday but the most weird thing is all my backups have no data after the 2014/06/06.

My server is a CentOS 6.5 (Final) with parallels 11.5.30
My DB is working with MyISAM so i have 3 files for each table MYD, Frm, MYI.
MYSQL Version is 5.1.73

There is my mysql log file:

```
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source dist
140626 00:58:44 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib
140626  0:58:45  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 512.0M
140626  0:58:45  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
140626  0:58:45  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
140626  0:58:45  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 284217240
140626  0:58:45 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140626  0:58:45 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.1.73'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source dist
```

I need to get my datas back and i m looking for any help or way to get them back

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are NOT general software tech support. Try the DBA site, maybe.

Comment: I did it but i m looking for anyway to resolve my problem.